# rails promote table row to top of table on if statement

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So i have this table:

```
<% @extra_dates.each do |ed| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ed.date %></td>
    <td><%= ed.eventvenuename %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Buy Now", "/events/" + ed.permalink, class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
    <% if ed.weburl1 || ed.weburl2 %>
      <td>
        <label class="annlabel" id="label">Cheapest</label>
      </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now if the cheapest label shows I want this to be on the top row of the table.

Comment: can you give more clear explanation of your problem?BTW there is a <th> tag for table header

Comment: You have to sort the data from your controller then. Can you show us what `@extra_dates` is?

Comment: @extra_dates = Event.where(eventname: @event.eventname)

Answer (score 0):

You should sort your collection in the controller:

```
@extra_dates = Event.where(eventname: @event.eventname).order("(COALESCE(weburl1, false) OR COALESCE(weburl2, false)) DESC")
```

This assumes that you are using PostgreSQL.

or

```
@extra_dates = Event.where(eventname: @event.eventname).sort_by {|e| (e.weburl1 ? 0 : 1) || (e.weburl2 ? 0 : 1)}
```

Have in mind that the second approach might be a lot slower for large collections.